# дублирование строк в датасете

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть датасет продаж ПК со столбцами "цена", "наименование", "объем ПЗУ", "продажи". В столбце "продажи" указано количество проданных ПК. Чтобы в дальнейшем правильно посчитать статистику, нужно учесть количество продаж. Как дублировать строки в датасет по количеству продаж?

таблица

| цена | наименование | объем ПЗУ | продажи |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 100 | 1 |
| 111 | 2 | 80 | 2 |
| 121 | 3 | 90 | 5 |
| 22 | 4 | 100 | 10 |

должна стать

| цена121 | наименование3 | объем ПЗУ90 | продажи5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 100 | 1 |
| 111 | 2 | 80 | 2 |
| 111 | 2 | 80 | 2 |
| 121 | 3 | 90 | 5 |
| 121 | 3 | 90 | 5 |
| 121 | 3 | 90 | 5 |
| 121 | 3 | 90 | 5 |
| 121 | 3 | 90 | 5 |
| 22 | 4 | 100 | 10 |

+еще 8 раз

| 22 | 4 | 100 | 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7060/178576)

Comment: в вопросе должен содержаться воспроизводимый пример данных и ваш код. сама формулировка вопроса - непонятна.

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос, можете показать пример датасета и того как он должен выглядеть после изменений?
Я правильно понимаю, что строка к примеру с количеством продаж 3, должна превратиться в 3 строки с количеством продаж 1?

Comment: @Step1709
да, все верно. то есть строка с "продажами" = 3 должна стать 3 строками с теми же данными (цена, название и тп)

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [`pd.Series.repeat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html#pandas-series-repeat), передав в качестве аргумента колонку с количеством, чтобы сгенерировать индексы согласно количеству (продаж), и передайте новый индекс в [`DataFrame.reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html#pandas-series-repeat) чтобы составить датафрейм с нужной индексацией и количеством повторов на каждый индекс.

```python
df = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['продажи']))
```

###### Результат:

```
   цена  наименование  объем ПЗУ  продажи
0    10             1        100        1
1   111             2         80        2
1   111             2         80        2
2   121             3         90        5
2   121             3         90        5
2   121             3         90        5
2   121             3         90        5
2   121             3         90        5
3    22             4        100       10
3    22             4        100       10
3    22             4        100       10
…    …              …         …         …
```

… и так далее

###### Весь код:

```python
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'цена': [10, 111, 121, 22],
    'наименование': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'объем ПЗУ': [100, 80, 90, 100],
    'продажи': [1, 2, 5, 10]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['продажи']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот вариант, который решит вашу проблему, но прошу учесть, что скорость работы у него будет не очень большая и может потребоваться время, если у вас большой датафрейм:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'цена': [10,111, 121, 22],
    'наименование': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'обьем ПЗУ': [100, 80, 90, 100],
    'продажи': [1, 2, 5, 10]
})

duplicated_df = pd.DataFrame()

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    count = row['продажи']
    duplicated_rows = pd.concat([row] * count, axis=1).T
    duplicated_df = pd.concat([duplicated_df, duplicated_rows], ignore_index=True)
```

Теперь в `duplicated_df` будут продублированы все строчки в зависимости от значения продаж в оригинальном датафрейме.

Comment: Значения из вопроса можно не переписывать, есть очень удобный [`pd.read_clipboard()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_clipboard.html#pandas-read-clipboard). Если таблицу из вопроса выделить и скопировать, она из буфера создастся с наименованиями колонок.

Comment: @DiMithras спасибо, не знал, что так можно)

Comment: если все-таки вам не удается избежать построковой итерации по датафрейму, то советую использовать `itertuples` вместо `iterrows` - это _существенно_ повысить эффективность кода.

Comment: @strawdog спасибо за совет, постараюсь учесть в будущем)