# Не получается продублировать строки по условию

Tags: python, pandas

Не получается продублировать строки по условию: строка должна быть продублирована столько раз сколько указано в столбце 'sale' и заменить в нем значение на 1.
Есть dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['1','2','3'], 
                 'sale':[5,3,3],
                 'name':['pc1','pc2','pc3'], 
                 'card':['vc1','vc2','vc3']})
```

нужен результат:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['1','1','1','1','1','2','2','2','3','3','3'], 
                  'sale':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                  'name':['pc1','pc1','pc1''pc1','pc1','pc2','pc2','pc2','pc3','pc3','pc3'], 
                  'card':['vc1','vc1','vc1','vc1','vc1','vc2','vc2','vc2','vc3','vc3','vc3']})
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html

Comment: аналогичный вопрос с ответами https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1528111/519463